# Using `@apollo/client` `ApolloClient.subscribe` in `redux-saga`

Tags: redux, apollo, apollo-client, redux-saga

I want to use `redux-saga` to manage event-driven changes in app state, while using `@apollo/client` to subscribe to changes on the GraphQL server.

- Are there best practices about how this may / can be done?
- Am I misusing `redux-saga` or `@apollo/client` by doing this?

An idea of how I expect this to function is as follows:

```
function* rootSaga () {
   yield fork(watchAccountBalance)
}

function* watchAccountBalance () {
   // @todo Create a subscription
   // @todo Every change on the subscription is passed as `balance`
   if (balance == 0.00) {
      yield put(notifyBalanceEmpty());
   }
}
```

Barring the ability to do this, it would result in the (already robust) codebase having many react hooks that dispatch actions to `redux-saga` when `useSubscription` responses change.

Simple implementation has the subscription response yielded from calling `apolloClient.subscribe` with the query.

```
function* subscribeAccountBalance() {
  const apolloClient: ApolloClient<NormalizedCacheObject> = yield call(getClient);
  const subscription = yield call([apolloClient, apolloClient.subscribe], {
    query: USER_BALANCE_SUBSCRIPTION,
  });
  console.log(TAG, 'subscription', {subscription});
}
```

The value of `subscription` is:
`LOG  home/saga subscription {"subscription": {"_subscriber": [Function anonymous]}}`

Answer (score 1):

It seems a bit weird, to be honest. The point of Apollo Client is already to manage your state for you - in most cases you shouldn't add Redux on top of that. (And I'm saying that from the unique position of being both an Apollo Client and Redux maintainer.)

Your data should probably stay in one system. If you are not using the Caching features of Apollo Client, there's a good chance that a lower-level library would suffice you. Or you skip Redux at that point and just let most be handled by Apollo.

Comment: With respect to this, I do understand it seems weird from the perspective of data management, being that both Redux and Apollo Client provide these, however I'm expressly using Redux-Saga for what I believe to be a better developer experience for controlling the user experience through particular journeys. Do you have some more insight on this (honing in on redux-saga for ux)?

Comment: Not really any more insights, I'm sorry. This is not a recommended pattern, so there are also no "best practices" around it.